# Items in GridLayout overlap?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I'm trying to create a simple GridLayout in kivy as follows:

in Python file:

```
class GroundTile(Widget):
    pass

class PPGame(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(PPGame, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        for x in range(5):
            t = GroundTile()
            self.add_widget(t)
        self.add_widget(Label(text='ASD'))
```

in pp.kv:

```
#:kivy 1.9.0

<GroundTile>:
    size: 50, 50
    pos_hint: {'x': 1, 'y': 1}
    Image:
        source: 'img/Tmp_frame.png'

<PPGame>:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 3
        rows: 2
```

I expect this code to create a 3*2 layout with 5 images and 1 text label. The app launches, but all I see is just one image in the bottom left corner with the label on top of it. Presumably, the rest of the images are also stacked under them. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `PPGame` inherit from `GridLayout` and `GroundTile` from `Image`:

```
class GroundTile(Image):
    pass

class PPGame(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(PPGame, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        for x in range(5):
            self.add_widget(GroundTile())
        self.add_widget(Label(text='ASD'))
```

and

```
#:kivy 1.9.0

<GroundTile>:
    size: 50, 50
    pos_hint: {'x': 1, 'y': 1}
    source: 'i1.png'

<PPGame>:
    cols: 3
    rows: 2
```

`Widget`s themselves do not take care of their children's positioning.